# What happens if Thunderbird attempts to use folders that do not exist on my webmail account?

Tags: thunderbird, webmail

[image: thunderbird screenshot]

([View larger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzARZ.png))

I am looking at the settings in Thunderbird, which connects to my GMX webmail account. There are four folders here that Thunderbird can use: "Sent," "Archives," "Drafts," and "Templates." I do have a "Sent" folder and a "Drafts" folder in my GMX account.

What would happen if I tried to use those other two folders which do not exist in GMX? For instance, if I wanted to save a template? Would Thunderbird try to upload the template to a nonexistent "Templates" folder and then just give me an error?

I'm kind of afraid to simply start experimenting with it in case I break or mess up things somehow, or produce some weird results.

My Thunderbird version is 13.0.

Comment: Oh I completely forgot to mention: I have it set up to use IMAP.

Answer (score 0):

Thunderbird will just store the files locally to your machine.

In the account settings menu you can change which folders sync where so if the archive and template folders do try to sync you can just turn them off and use them locally.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the server type (and capabilities perhaps). For instance, in my Gmail account, the folders get created with the label "Imap/Drafts" and my office mail account which is a POP account, doesn't provide the functionality and hence the folders are created locally.

Answer (score 0):

You can apparently remedy this by clicking on your account home page, where it has headings like 'Email', 'Accounts', and under 'Advanced Features' click 'Manage folder subscriptions.' This will bring up a dialog box with a tab labeled 'Folder List',  in this list are all the folders Thunderbird will use to connect to your online account. I got my Thunderbird client into a state where I had subscribed to a folder that was deleted, which would cause an error when attempting to connect to the folder. I fixed it by removing the subscription to the folder, which was then removed completely from the list and from my sidebar.